# Storing post bodies in database or files?

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

I'm learning web-centric programming by writing myself a blog, using PHP with a MySQL database backend. This should replace my current (Drupal based) blog.

I've decided that a `post` should contain some data: `id`, `userID`, `title`, `content`, `time-posted`. That makes a nice schema for a database table. I'm having issues deciding how I want to organize the storage of `content`, though.

I could either:

1. Use a file-based system. The database table `content` would then be a URL to a locally-located file, which I'd then read, format, and display.
2. Store the entire contents of the post in `content`, ie put it into the database.

If I went with (1), searching the contents of posts would be slightly problematic - I'd be limited to metadata searching, or I'd have to read the contents of each file when searching (although I don't know how much of a problem that'd be - `grep -ir "string" .` isn't *too* slow...). However, images (if any) would be referenced by a URL, so referencing `content` would at least be an internally consistant methodology, and I'd be *easily* able to reuse the content, as text files are ridiculously easy to work with, compared to an SQL database file.

Going with (2), though, I could use a [`longtext`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html). The `content` would then need to be sanitised before I tried to put it into the tuple, and I'm limited by size (although, it's unlikely that I'd write a 4GB blog post ;). Searching would be easy.

I don't (currently) see which way would be (a) easier to implement, (b) easier to live with.

Which way should I go / how is this normally done? Any further pros / cons for either (1) or (2) would be appreciated.

Comment: indexing etc would be a problem and also u if you have a database you can store the data in multiple tables and relate them with foreign keys etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the 'current generation', implementing a database is pretty much your safest bet. As you mentioned, it's pretty standard, and you outlined all of the fun stuff. Most SQL instances have a fairly powerful FULLTEXT (or equivalent) search. 
You'll probably have just as much architecture to write between the two you outlined, especially if you want one to have the feature-parity of the other.

The up-and-coming technology is a key/value store, commonly referred to as [`NoSQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). With this, you can store your content and metadata into separate individual documents, but in a structured way that makes searching and retrieval quite fast. Some common NoSQL engines are [`mongo`](http://www.mongodb.org/), [`CouchDB`](http://couchdb.apache.org/), and [`redis`](http://redis.io/) (among others).

Ultimately this comes down to personal preference, along with a few use-case considerations. You didn't really outline what is important to you as far as conveniences and your application. Any one of these would be just fine for a personal or development blog. Building an entire platform with multiple contributors is a different conversation.

Answer (score 1):

13 years ago I tried your option 1 (having external files for text content) - not with a blog, but with a CMS. And I ended in shoveling it all back into the database for easier handling. It's much easier to have global replaces on the database than on the text file level. With large numbers of post you run into trouble with directory sizes and access speed, or you have to manage subdirectory schemes etc. etc. Stick to the database only approach-
There are some tools to make your life easier with text files than the built-in mysql functions, but with a command line client like mysql and mysqldump you can easily extract any texts to the file system level, work on them with standard tools and re-load them into the database. What mysql really lacks is built-in support for regex search/replace, but even for that you'll find a patch if you're willing to recompile mysql.